# Why data exist in multiple locations in 8086 in the same physical memory?

Tags: x86-16, memory-address, memory-segmentation

In 8086 more than one logical addresses (`segment:offset`) can have the same physical address (`001F:000F` and `000F:010F` are the same addresses, like `001F:000F = 01F0+000F = 01FF` in the same way as `000F:010F = 01FF`).

In physical memory, any programs see the logical memory address. So more than one program can have data (byte) at the same physical address (though the logical addresses are different) position. Why don't they collide with each other? Why don't we lose data???

Comment: Could you explain why you believe they are the same 'address' - what do you mean by 'address'? They look like they are in different segments. Also, why are you saying that they're 20-bit addresses?  Are you referring to the size of the address bus instead? (Which I admit are arguably the same thing, in some contexts).

Comment: Guys: It's only been 15 minutes. Give Mehedee a chance to reword the question, see http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html for some useful background information

Comment: @Arafangion: 8086 uses `segment:offset` address type, not flat address space. The address is calculated according to the formula `segment*16 + offset`, so the 2 addresses points to the same memory location

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: So can you answer the original question, what you've done is explained why such a question might be asked. :)  I'm attempting to get a better, clarified question to be asked.

Comment: they are the logical addresses .I mean different logical address have same physical address . like 001F:000F = 01F0+000F = 01FF in the same way 000F:010F = 01FF in physical memory ... any program sees the logical memory address ... so more than one program can have same physical (though the logical addresses are different) address ... why don't they collide with each other ?

Comment: They don't collide because they are the same thing.  It's kind of like phone numbers: You could call someone using 12341234, or you could add their country code, 6112341234.  The fact that both refer to the same phone does not mean that there is a conflict, however, please update your question above so that visitors don't need to look at the comments, and so that a proper answer can be provided. :)

Comment: @MehedeeHassan: assuming you're talking about real-mode 8086 (which is the only thing supported on an actual 8086), then the two different segment:offset representations of the same physical address would in fact 'collide'.  They would both access the exact same physical memory location.

Comment: You should look into how your OS manages process memory space. [Love](http://www.amazon.com/Linux-Kernel-Development-3rd-Edition/dp/0672329468) chapter 15 "Process address space" is a possible linux reference for you.

Comment: cirosantilli: What OS?  What OS does your keyboard run? Or your calculator. There is no Linux distribution that runs on this CPU;  We're talking firmware here.

Comment: @Arafangion I think it is likely that the OP wants to know how multiple process run concurrently on a single RAM, and this depends on how your OS manages RAM.

Comment: @cirosantilli: Umm, multiple processes?  What's a process?  There is no such concept for 8086, you have the CPU executing code, linearly. That's... Just about it.  Of course, you could define it, but you would need to write the supporting framework for that, and it would be particular to your specific project.  And there is no memory protection, and they all share the stack.

Comment: @cirosantilli: Upon re-reading the OP's question, I can see how you would interpret that question that way, and it could well indeed be what they wanted to know, I'll upvote your comment, sorry for being agressive there. :)

Comment: @Arafangion no prob! =)

Comment: thanks @ Michael Burr ,@cirosantilli ,@Arafangion .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 8086 can address 1MB of memory, requiring 20 bits to specify the address of any particular byte. Since the 8086's registers only hold 16 bits, the segment model was developed which gives each of those 1M addresses many different names. Just as the number `4` can be named as `0+4`, `1+3`, `2+2`, etc., the address `12345` can be expressed as `1234:0005`, `1233:0015`, `1230:0045`, and so on.

In other words, each physical address has 64k different logical addresses. This means that if one program is accessing `1234:0005` and another program is accessing `1233:0015`, those two programs will be accessing the exact same memory address.

So how do we prevent different programs from "colliding" with each other? First of all, recognize that modern computers do not use 8086es anymore. If you have multiple programs running on an actual 8086, they are probably cooperating with each other, sharing the address space knowingly.

Modern CPUs do not run in the 1MB segmented mode (called "real mode") anymore. If you run an OS like Windows or Linux, the CPU uses something called *virtual memory*, where each program has its own mapping of logical addresses to physical addresses. In this mode, the programs typically use logical addresses that are 32 or 64 bits, and the programs have no knowledge of how a given logical address maps to a physical address. Any number of programs can use the same set of logical addresses and there will be no overlap of physical addresses unless the programs specifically arrange to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In DOS programs can't run simultaneously, so there's no problem of collision.

In multitasking OSes each process runs on its own address space specified by the OS. Their logical address maps to different physical addresses (except for shared memory locations) so there won't be any collision either.

Comment: Aren't TSRs essentially programs that run at the same time as whatever other program you're running?

Comment: Yes, but they lies in another segment, and if they need dynamic memory allocation, they'll use DOS memory allocation service so the problem seems not to appear